# Matplotlib - Python can not get the minor tick labels to show every month

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range('01/01/2016', datetime.today(), freq = 'M')
X = pd.DataFrame(index = dates)
X['values'] = np.random.rand(len(X)) * 300

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(8 * phi, 8 )
X['values'].plot(ax = ax)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '$ {:,.0f}'.format(x)))
plt.show()
```

[image: Can't show every month]

I've been trying for half an hour now and I really need some help with this.

What is the cleanest, simplest way to show  the other months on the minor tick labels  for the xaxis? Instead of what it wants to do for some reason, show only months that start with a J....

Notes: I do have seaborne installed.

Comment: `plt.xticks(X, np.arange(len(X))`? Can you provide a [MCVE] to better understand your dataframe?

Comment: @HarvIpan Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in order to be able to use matplotlib tickers on pandas date plots you needs to set the compatibility option `x_compat=True`.

```
X.plot(ax = ax, x_compat=True)
```

Next, in order to format the x axis, you needs to use `xaxis`. In order to set the minor ticklabels, you need to use `set_minor_formatter`.

In order to assign some ticks to certain positions you need a `Locator` not a `Formatter`.

Now it seems you want to have full control over the output plot, hence you need to set the major *and* minor locators *and* formatters.

Note that labeling each month will surely let the labels overlap. So a larger figure or smaller fontsize would be needed.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,3))

X.plot(ax = ax, x_compat=True)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("\n%Y"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b"))

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, ha="center")
plt.show()
```

[image]